# Count the number of occurrences of a character in a list in prolog

Tags: arrays, list, prolog

```
walls(This) :- 
    append(This, NewMap),
    length(NewMap, N),
    numWalls(NewMap, W),
    W >= N/10.

numWalls([], _, 0).
numWalls('w'|Tail, W) :-
    W is W1 + 1,
    numWalls(Tail, W1).
numWalls(_|Tail, W):-
    numWalls(Tail, W).
```

I comment out line by line and get false until i take out the numWalls(NewMap,W), line. The append flattens a 2-dimensional array and length returns the proper length of the flattened map. We need to count how many times a 'w' appears in the list of lists and if more than 10% of the list is 'w' return True.

---

```
walls(Maps) :- 
    append(Maps, NewMap),
    length(NewMap, N),
    print(NewMap),
    numWalls(NewMap, W),
    print(W) .

numWalls([], 0).
numWalls(['w'|Tail], W) :-
    numWalls(Tail, W1),
    W1 is W-1.
numWalls([_|Tail], W):-
    numWalls(Tail, W).
```

"ERROR: is/2: Arguments are not sufficiently instantiated"
Looks like the error is with my is statement?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like you are missing some square brackets. Other than that minor syntax issue, your program logic is fine:

```
numWalls([], 0).
numWalls(['w'|Tail], W) :-
    numWalls(Tail, W1),
    W is W1 + 1.
numWalls([H|Tail], W):-
    H \= (w),
    numWalls(Tail, W).
```

**EDIT:** As [false](https://stackoverflow.com/users/772868/false) commented, the second rule needs to change against consuming a `w` by mistake, to avoid `numWalls([w,w], 0).` from succeeding.

[Link to a demo on ideone.](http://ideone.com/j0RHId)

Comment: Arguments are not sufficiently instantiated after fixing the brackets. Also needed to change the W is W1+1 to W is W1-1 i believe.

Comment: @theB3RV Try switching around the recursive call and the addition line.

Comment: Switching them around got rid of the error, i took out W >= N/10 and put a print(W) statement in its place and it will not print out W.

Comment: @theB3RV I missed the second arg on the first line - it's going to work once you remove the middle arg.

Comment: I actually did that, accidentally left it in the code on here. still getting "not sufficiently instantiated."

Comment: Whichever piece of code comes second inside that second "numWalls()" rule is the error.

Comment: @theB3RV What's the version of Prolog that you are using? This works fine on SWI ([link to ideone](http://ideone.com/cF5pOx)).

Comment: running it on a school's server. SWI 5.10.2

Comment: when i changed the W is W1 + 1, it broke. Thanks for all your help :D

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: `numWalls([w,w],0)` succeeds incorrectly. You need a clean guard in the last clause.

Comment: @false You are absolutely right, thank you very much! This is now fixed.

Comment: Nit: You do not need to write `'w'` for `w` but to be 100% sure, write `H \= (w)`.